# ZF3 module zend-console show only html

Tags: zend-framework3

I added zendframework/zend-console with composer and follow the [tutorial](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-console/intro/) but when i launch bin/zf (link of `php public/index.php` ) I see only my first website page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add  'Zend\Mvc\Console', in modules.config.php